# "This is What the Japan Earthquake Sounded Like..."

Tags: interesting

According to this website, this clip claims to be a an audio recording of the earthquake in Japan.

http://fooyoh.com/news/5919440

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It's a horrifying sound! The footage is incredible. Imagine hearing this rumble as you see your life float away. Frightening. 

Comment: in a related story, you might want to look at this:
http://blip.tv/file/1662914

Answer (score 1):

Source:
[Listening to the deep ocean environment](http://listentothedeep.com/acoustics/index.html)